# Pre-Generate Views to Improve Query Performance

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I was trying to improve the performance by following [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx),

I already have my model and i dont have and `edmx` files
and the steps asked to have one so i created one and followed [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716703%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
the created created models for every table i have.

How can i let the edmx file use the existing models without creating now one and what other things do you recommend me to do to by pass other issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using EF5 - you could do it the following way (in order for this to work, all of your models must be in the same namespace):

1. Click the design surface of the edmx file, and set the Namespace property to the namespace where your models exist.
2. You should have the following files underneath your edmx file:

   - YourModelName.Context.tt
   - YourModelName.Designer.cs
   - YourModelName.edmx.diagram
   - YourModelName.tt

Delete the YourModelName.tt file the auto generated models will no longer be created, and if you've set your namespace correctly (step 1) entity framework should use your models instead.